# Please help me setting up codeigniter and phpunit

Tags: codeigniter, phpunit

I have created few simple apps in codeigniter never tested it. Can anyone give me some links or explain how to setup codeigniter with phpunit ? Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ciunit fork works well and it is compatible with the latest CI 2.1

https://bitbucket.org/kenjis/my-ciunit

Answer (score 1):

http://www.knollet.com/foostack/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @tombom While I generally agree with you, it's a link to a project, not an "answer" in the general sense. The only thing I could write is "use foostack", but I'd still need to link to the project. The project itself is the answer to the question.

Comment: Okay, maybe I was a bit fast when reviewing, was actually just clicking through, to be honest.